# Updating and organizing overlays on an MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, overlay

I want to do overlays on an MKMapView. So I created my custom object:

```
@interface Spot : NSObject

@property int spot_id;
@property CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property float radius;
@property NSObject<MKOverlay> * overlay;

- (id) initWithSpotId:(int)spot_id position:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate andRadius:(float)radius;

@end
```

There is a backend, that constantly updates the Spots and delivers them to the phone. So I have to:

- Check if the currently rendered spots are still valid and there
- If yes, have they moved or changed radius? If so, update them (move? / delete + redraw?!)
- Delete if they don't exist anymore.

Is there a better way of keeping track of the overlays? Keeping an `NSObject<MKoverlay> *`  reference attached to each spot and constantly reassigning it feels a bit strange to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there are three questions here:

1. How to detect changes in spots in your server?

   The ugly way to do this would be iterate through your spots and see if the `coordinate` and/or `radius` changed. A little better would be to have the server update create, modify, and delete timestamps or some other identifier so the client would have the ability to retrieve all creations, modifications, and/or deletions since the last update. Best would be to marry that with some form of push notification, so the client would also be proactively notified of these changes.

   This question is difficult to answer in the abstract. It depends a lot upon the capabilities of your server and the nature of the database (e.g. how many "spots", how frequently do they change, etc.). This impacts both the client-server architecture, but also the client implementation.
2. How to update the map when a spot changes?

   This is a far easier question. Insertions and deletions are easy. You just do `addOverlay:` (or, in iOS 7, `addOverlay:level:` and `removeOverlay:`. For updates, while it's inelegant, I think the easiest way is to just remove the old overlay and add it back in and `viewForOverlay` will take care of the user interface for you.
3. What is the right structure of the `Spot` class?

   Just as a thought, but it seems duplicative to have your `coordinate` and `radius` properties, and then have a `id<MKOverlay> overlay` object too (because that's presumably a `MKCircle` with the same two properties). If your overlays are going to be `MKCircle` objects, it might be easier to just have a `Spot` class, itself, to conform to `MKOverlay`:

   ```
   @interface Spot : NSObject <MKOverlay>

   @property (nonatomic) int spot_id;
   @property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
   @property (nonatomic) CLLocationDistance radius;
   @property (nonatomic, readonly) MKMapRect boundingMapRect;

   - (id) initWithSpotId:(int)spot_id position:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate andRadius:(CLLocationDistance)radius;

   @end
   ```

   Then, all you need to do is to implement `boundingMapRect` and `intersectsMapRect`:

   ```
   - (MKMapRect) boundingMapRect
   {
       MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.coordinate);
       CLLocationDistance distance = self.radius * MKMetersPerMapPointAtLatitude(self.coordinate.latitude);
       MKMapRect rect = MKMapRectMake(point.x, point.y, distance * 2.0, distance * 2.0);
       rect = MKMapRectOffset(rect, -distance, -distance);

       return rect;
   }

   - (BOOL)intersectsMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
   {
       return MKMapRectIntersectsRect(mapRect, [self boundingMapRect]);
   }
   ```

   You might want to double-check that `boundingMapRect` logic, but I think it's right.

   Then you can just add and remove `Spot` objects as overlays themselves. And all you need to do is to implement a `viewForOverlay` in your `MKMapViewDelegate`, for example, in iOS versions prior to 7, that would be:

   ```
   - (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
   {
       if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[Spot class]])
       {
           Spot *spot       = (id)overlay;
           MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:spot.coordinate
                                                            radius:spot.radius];

           MKCircleView *overlayView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:circle];
           overlayView.fillColor     = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
           overlayView.strokeColor   = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
           overlayView.lineWidth     = 3.0;
           return overlayView;
       }

       return nil;
   }
   ```

   In iOS 7, that would be:

   ```
   - (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
   {
       if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[Spot class]])
       {
           Spot *spot       = (id)overlay;
           MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:spot.coordinate
                                                            radius:spot.radius];

           MKCircleRenderer *renderer = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:circle];
           renderer.fillColor         = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
           renderer.strokeColor       = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
           renderer.lineWidth         = 3;

           return renderer;
       }

       return nil;
   }
   ```

   Another approach would be to define your `Spot` as:

   ```
   @interface Spot : NSObject <MKOverlay>

   @property (nonatomic) int spot_id;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) MKCircle *overlay;

   - (id) initWithSpotId:(int)spot_id position:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate andRadius:(CLLocationDistance)radius;
   ```

   And you could then just define `boundingMapRect` and `coordinate` return the appropriate values from the `MKCircle` (saving you from having to write your own):

   ```
   - (MKMapRect)boundingMapRect
   {
       return [self.circle boundingMapRect];
   }

   - (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
   {
       return [self.circle coordinate];
   }
   ```

   Clearly the `init` method would change:

   ```
   - (id) initWithSpotId:(int)spot_id position:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate andRadius:(CLLocationDistance)radius;
   {
       self = [super init];
       if (self) {
           _spot_id = spot_id;
           _circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coordinate radius:radius];
       }
       return self;
   }
   ```

   As would the `viewForOverlay` (iOS versions prior to 7.0) in the `MKMapViewDelegate`:

   ```
   - (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
   {
       if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[SpotCircle class]])
       {
           SpotCircle *spot = (id)overlay;

           MKCircleView *overlayView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:spot.circle];
           overlayView.fillColor     = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
           overlayView.strokeColor   = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
           overlayView.lineWidth     = 3.0;

           return overlayView;
       }

       return nil;
   }
   ```

   In iOS 7, that would be:

   ```
   - (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
   {
       if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[SpotCircle class]])
       {
           SpotCircle *spot = (id)overlay;

           MKCircleRenderer *renderer = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:spot.circle];
           renderer.fillColor         = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
           renderer.strokeColor       = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
           renderer.lineWidth         = 3;

           return renderer;
       }

       return nil;
   }
   ```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the different ideas and the example code! You noticed correctly, I need an MKCircle. What I'm doing now is: `@interface Spot : MKCircle`. That makes it really easy. Removing and adding is also working. Server notification is still in the works, so thanks for the hints there as well!

Comment: @kadrian I didn't suggest that because `MKCircle` is immutable, so if your spot changes, you have to discard the old `Spot` and then create a new one. It works, but doesn't feel right from a data modeling perspective. But if that works for you, that's great.